# How to compare Android contacts mob number with app user mob number so that users can see their friends with the app only?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse as the backend for my application.

Just like whatsapp, if you have a registered users phone number in your local contacts, then you can view and message that contact on the application. You add new contacts through phone numbers.

Do I upload the phones entire database of contacts and store it on Parse?
How can I programm Parse to search the uploaded list for any numbers that are already registered in the database?

Comment: The answer of this "Do I upload the phones entire database of contacts and store it on Parse?" is definitely no. For the possible answer I will look forward.